# Disabling "Fast Startup" in Windows 8 through programmig

Tags: windows, windows-8

Is there a way to disable (turn off) the "Fast Startup" power option in Windows 8 through programming?

Answer (score 4):

[You can do it through the registry](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/6320-fast-startup-turn-off-windows-8-a.html) at `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Power`

Creating/setting a `DWORD` key called `HiberbootEnabled` with the value `0` will turn fast boot off.

Since you're not asking about a specific language, I can't do a code sample, but sample bat scripts are downloadable at the link above.

Comment: Thank you; I will try that out. Programming language doesn't matter for this; so I am good if this registry works.